# Overwrite webform-submission-information.tpl.php for only one node

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming, drupal-webform

I'm trying to show the view submission to users just for one Webform and I'm trying to modify the information template. I've tried webform-submission-information-29.tpl.php and is not working.

I have also seen the hook webform-theme but I'm not sure how to modify it as to make it read templates for nodes.

Any idea of how to do this?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

In specific theme create the tpl  :

webform-submission-[webform-nid].tpl.php

acces to array of values from submission :

```
 <?php print_r($renderable); ?>
```

do not forget clear cache!